# Is this formula for the optimal test statistic well-known?

Tags: pr.probability

Consider a random vector $X$ in $\mathbb R^n$. Under the null hypothesis, $X$ has probability density distribution $f$. However, the experimenter has a strong suspicion that $X$ actually satisfies probability density distribution $g$. Now the experimenter will take one sample $S$ of $X$. The goal of the experimenter is, to obtain a p value which is very small. A p-value is defined as a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $[0,1]$, given by $p(S)=P(T(Z)\geq T(S)\mid Z\sim H_0)$, where $T$ is some test statistic and $H_0$ is the null hypothesis.
I have found a proof (which I'll omit here) that the best test statistic is:
$$T(S):=\frac{g(S)}{f(S)}.$$

The corresponding p-value $p_T$ is optimal in the following sense: suppose that $p_U$ is another p-value. If the experimenter's suspicion is true that $X$ has pdf $g$, then for all $s\in[0,1]$, the probability that $p_T(S)\leq s$ is at least the probability that $p_U(S)\leq s$.

Is this result well-known and does it have a name? Also, is this used in practice?

(Note that this test statistic is also the Bayes factor)

Comment: I think this is a restatement of the Neyman--Pearson lemma. (Your notation: $T$ vs. $T(S)$ is not good. Also, the formula $X\in\mathbb R^n$ makes no sense, as $X$ is a map to $\mathbb R^n$, not a vector in $\mathbb R^n$.)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Do you have a suggestion on how I could rewrite $X\in \mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Just say $X$ is a random vector in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the Neyman—Pearson lemma. The corresponding test statistic is the likelihood ratio test. Thank you!